# Calling a python function when submitting using WTForms

Tags: python, flask, web, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to implement an image compression script when an image for a profile is uploaded using WTForms. However, I've had a little trouble understanding how to set it up.

Here's my code:

```
    class Profile(FlaskForm):

        photo = FileField('Profile Picture')
        submit = SubmitField('Save Changes')
        def resize400(inputImg): *image compression code here*
```

Resize works by itself when I run it, so all I need is a image file input.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the validate_on_submit() function in the routes page rather than embedding it into the Form Class. i.e

```
class Profile(FlaskForm):

    photo = FileField('Profile Picture')
    submit = SubmitField('Save Changes')
```

Routes (or views) page:

```
@app.route('/uploadProfile', methods=['GET', 'POST']
def upload_profile():
    form = Profile()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        photo = form.photo.data
        resize400(photo)
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))
```

Don't forget to import it with

```
from forms import Profile
```